# Rails Tutorial Chapter 9.2.2 - Failing authorisation tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I am following through the Rails Tutorial and hit a roadblock. On section 9.2.2. http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec-requiring_the_right_user

```
........................................................FFF...........

Failures:

  1) Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action 
     Failure/Error: before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:37:in `sign_in'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:71:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action 
     Failure/Error: before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:37:in `sign_in'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:71:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action 
     Failure/Error: before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:37:in `sign_in'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:71:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 3.1 seconds
70 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:75 # Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action 
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:76 # Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action 
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:81 # Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action 

Randomized with seed 40912
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong.

The source code is available at so I do not clutter this page:
https://bitbucket.org/davidhughes85/brand_new/src

Comment: fix the link to the code source or add your spec here, especially file  `./spec/support/utilities.rb` (near line 37)

Comment: did you happen to find the error? I'm having the same issue, it looks as the function isn't being recognized, weird thing that `valid_sign(user)` does work, but `sign_in(user, options={})` is not, and both are in the same file, my guess is that ruby is mixing the sign_in definition on SessionsHelper, the question is why? and even changing the name of the def in utilities.rb doesn't work either. I'm stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. It took me a while to find it, but the issue was in `utilities.rb` file. Look at the method `def sign_in(user, options={ })`

The issue is that you've probably written:

```
def sign_in(user, options={ })
  if options[:no_capybara]
    # Sign in when not using Capybara
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attributes(:remember_token, User.digest(remember_token))
  else
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Email",     with: user.email
    fill_in "Password",  with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
  end
end
```

You should write:

```
def sign_in(user, options={ })
  if options[:no_capybara]
    # Sign in when not using Capybara
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.digest(remember_token))
  else
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Email",     with: user.email
    fill_in "Password",  with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
  end
end
```

The difference is that you've written in the `if` block `user.update_attributes(...)`. You should instead write `user.update_attribute(...)`. It's an issue of accidental pluralization of a method call.

Answer (score 0):

I have a guess, although the link to the code is dead - in the [exercise](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code-sign_in_helper) the `sign_in` API looks like this:

```
def sign_in(user, options={})
  if options[:no_capybara]
    # Sign in when not using Capybara.
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.hash(remember_token))
  else
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
  end
end
```

The error message says that there is a `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)` in `sign_in`. and since the only line accepting two arguments (given that `before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }`) is `user.update_attribute`, and that in the exercise page also has `user.update_attributes` which receives a single argument, my money is on you having a typo on the line:

```
def sign_in(user, options={})
  if options[:no_capybara]
    # Sign in when not using Capybara.
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attributes(:remember_token, User.hash(remember_token)) # <== TYPO
  else
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your environment is not aware of your function, probably you wrote it while running some test was running (don't know for real), try to reset your test environment by using 
`rake test:prepare`
This should fix your issue, hope it helps someone having the same issue.